# Software and site scope

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been a couple of questions recently regarding websites and software on the main site that I interpret as being off topic. Namely these two questions:

- [Body animation](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36418/is-there-a-body-animator-i-can-use-to-demonstrate-exercise-movements) - Asking for a software package that can be used to do body animations for exercise demonstration
- [Website/PDF of examples](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36627/catalogue-for-exercise-names-and-images) - Asking for a catalog of exercises with images

The way that I look at them is that they are not really on topic, as they do not fit in what we consider to be on topic (From the help section):

- improving your exercise performance or technique
- choosing a training program
- nutrition as it relates to exercise
- **gear and gadgets used during exercise**
- achieving physique milestones
- injury prevention

I bolded the one that they *might* fall under. However, the first one (in my opinion) does not enable the average user to improve their program. Knowing that there is an animator still relies on someone to *use* that animator to create exercise demonstrations, and that is also reliant on the skill and understanding of the person doing the programming. The end product might be helpful/on topic in an answer, but the process and the tool(s) are not on topic.

For the second, I am on the fence about this question, leaning towards either off topic or possibly a community wiki of good reference sites. Again, just knowing that it is there is not really useful in and of itself, there is a program context that is lacking.

I'd like some feedback on this, with reasons why you do or do not think that the questions are on topic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to agree that these questions are not on topic especially the two in particular. I remember seeing these kinds of questions a long time ago (in the early years of Fitness), and they weren't good questions either.

These kinds of questions asked for lists of items. They *could* be helpful, but they get away from any modicum of specificity. The intention of a question shouldn't turn into a be-all, end-all monolithic encyclopedic page about a topic.

More importantly, what makes these questions not on topic is that they also entertain recommendations which fall under the kinds of [questions that should not be asked](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm kind of inclined towards the first one and not the second. It's useful to have a way to illustrate a movement, not for doing it yourself necessarily, but for demonstrating it to someone else. Admittedly, one could argue that taking a video of yourself doing the exercise might be better in some ways, but it loses the ability to modify the angle of display.

The second I just didn't like because it boiled down to "What is a chart of all the exercises?" although I think it could have worked in a more constrained question like "Is there a poster-sized chart of common stretches?"