# Straight "recommend this" questions - On topic or not?

Tags: discussion

This is related to [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41754/finding-online-personal-trainers-international) related to finding a personal online trainer.

In the past, questions like these have been considered to be off topic (See [this meta](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/749/software-and-site-scope) as an example), as they are very opinion based and personal recommendation, and there is no real question to be answered.

I would like to see how the community feels about these questions.

Answer (score 4):

I vote to close, even though I consider the question completely valid, and something that *should* be asked. I just don't know that it fits with our current guidelines.

It's a very contemporary question, in the sense that online personal trainers is a concept that might be newer than a large portion of our rule set. Perhaps we ought to give them an overhaul.

However, I interpret it as asking for a purchase recommendation of sorts, which is directly off-topic.

Comment: I'm giving this my +1. I'm a bit on the fence since we have "what's a good resource for XYZ" questions but they're about exercise and this is about resources for hiring a professional.

Comment: In the same vein of thought, if someone asked: "what are some things to look out for when hiring an online personal trainer?" would that be on-topic or off-topic? That's a perfectly valid question to me but I'm not certain where it lies in our list of approved questions.

Comment: @C.Lange - That's something I'd argue is on-topic. We already have a lot of answers that indicate how to spot faults in a program or regimen. They'd be very similar to how we'd spot faults in a trainer, be it online or otherwise.

Comment: @C.Lange - I won't close your question yet, so if you want to edit it to reflect that emphasis, I imagine a *really* good answer would include at least one example of a "good" online trainer.

Comment: @JohnP - not my question, I think you're looking for Olav? I was just participating in the discussion.

Comment: @C.Lange - oops.